# How to add this in floating left in joomla

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, addthis

My site is http://www.philipgunwhy.com.

I want to add add this button like http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/top-10-social-media-blogs-the-2012-winners/ floats in the left in joomla. But currently i cannot do this by adding addthis module to my joomla website.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: A.This question is too vague B.Why can't you? C. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I have installed addthis module but i cannot show the buttons  always be visible in the same place, along the left side of the screen.

Comment: You're asking about an extension which you haven't specified, and you haven't told us how it's implemented. You're going to have to help us help you.

Comment: This is addthis extension of joomla

Comment: If it's an extension you have downloaded, I think you should be contacting the developers for support.